# Xamarin Forms Handle Hyperlinks in Webview Navigating issue

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Im developing a app that has some content pages from our CMS
that needs to be displayed into a `WebView` since they have HTML with some hyperlinks in it

Im controlling the hyperlinks wich is working as expected on android 
im doing this with the `Navigating` of the Xamarin.Forms.WebView event

im able to use `e.Url` to send the user to a internal page.

**Example:**

```
public class HybridWebView : WebView
{
    public String Code { get; set; }

    public HybridWebView()
    {
        Navigating += HybridWebView_Navigating;
    }


    private void HybridWebView_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
       if(e.Url.EndsWith(".aspx")
       {
          var CMS = new CMSView(e.Code, null);
          Navigation.PushAsync(CMS);
          e.Cancel = true;
       }
    }
}
```

Note this works well !

The problem is:

when i try this on iOS i got a blank/white `WebView`.
i tried to make a CustomRenderer on iOS but since i subclass the WebView to customize it i can't reach the properties `Code` for example.

How can i reach the properties in the custom renderer for ios? i know `e.NewElement` but `ShouldStartLoad` expects UIWebView and not my custom HybridWebView.

Does anyone has any tips or idea's how i can reach this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your customer renderer (a subclass of WebViewRenderer I assume) you can cast e.newElement to your HybridWebView type, e.g.:

```
HybridWebView wv = e.NewElement as HybridWebView;
```

Then you should be able to access your `Code` property with `wv.Code`.

Also the `NativeView` property of the `WebViewRenderer` will give you the iOS native `UIView` to work with. You should be able to cast this to a UIWebView without issue. E.g:

```
UIWebView nativeUIWebView = NativeView as UIWebView;
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thnx jgoldberger i dont need to cast e.NewElement since it knows its from type of hybridview but how can i use ShouldStartLoad it expects UIWebView as param and i need to use Hybridview there.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, the NativeView I mentioned should be what the base renderer has created for your HybridWebView. So this should be the UIWebView to use with ShouldStartLoad, unless I am misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `ShouldStartLoad`, you'll need to implement a custom `UIWebViewDelegate` for the native `UIWebView` being used. This can get tricky because if you replace the existing delegate with a custom one, you'll lose some of the built-in features that Xamarin.Forms `WebView` provides. Here is the strategy I use to get the best of both:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (WebView), typeof (CustomWebViewRenderer))]
public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged (VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);

        if (e.OldElement == null) {

            // Need to capture the existing one so we don't loose functionality 
            // that Xamarin.Forms already has
            var existingDelegate = Delegate;

            // Make sure to pass the existing one to the new one
            Delegate = new MyCustomWebViewDelegate(existingDelegate);
        }
    }
}

public class MyCustomWebViewDelegate : UIWebViewDelegate
{
    readonly UIWebViewDelegate existingDelegate;

    public MyCustomWebViewDelegate(UIWebViewDelegate existing)
    {
        existingDelegate = existing;
    }

    public override bool ShouldStartLoad (UIWebView webView, NSUrlRequest request, UIWebViewNavigationType navigationType)
    {
        // You can customize this instead of returning the existingDelegate method
        return existingDelegate.ShouldStartLoad(webView, request, navigationType);
    }

    public override void LoadFailed (UIWebView webView, NSError error)
    {
        existingDelegate.LoadFailed(webView, error);
    }


    public override void LoadingFinished (UIWebView webView)
    {
        existingDelegate.LoadingFinished(webView);
    }


    public override void LoadStarted (UIWebView webView)
    {
        existingDelegate.LoadStarted(webView);
    }

}
```

> Note* On iOS, WebViewRenderer inherits directly from UIWebView, so you don't have a Control property work with. You are a direct subclass of UIWebView and have access to the properties you would expect. See source [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/2.3.0/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/WebViewRenderer.cs).

You can add custom login to the `MyCustomWebViewDelegate.ShouldStartLoad` method.